# Is it a bad idea to start a thread in init method?

Tags: python

I have a class which acts like a Queue in which I am creating a worker thread. This worker thread would be responsible for processing each item from the queue.

Since an instance of this class should always have a worker thread, I am creating and starting the worker thread in the init method itself.

I would like to know if it is a bad practice to do so.

e.g

```
class CustomQueue:

    def __init__(self):
        # some initialization
        self.worker = threading.Thread(target=sometarget)
        self.worker.start()
```

Comment: This question was asked here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/165064/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-start-a-thread-in-init-method but I was told that codereview is not the right place for these kind of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I would go so far as to call it bad practice, but my
first instinct is to avoid all side-effects in constructors:
don't talk to DBs, don't interact with the file system, don't make
web requests, and, no, don't spin up processes or threads. Whenever possible,
**object instantiation should be a cheap, lightweight operation**.

This general rule is particularly useful when it comes to testing
and debugging. For example, imagine this scenario:

```
class CustomQueue:

    def __init__(self):
        # Side effects here...

    def fubb(self, x, y):
        ...
```

If you want to unit test `fubb()`, or perhaps interact with it in the Python
REPL, it's fairly annoying to have to think about all those side-effects.

There are exceptions to most rules, and if it really makes sense for
this class to take immediate action, one workaround is to add an
optional parameter to support your testing/debugging use cases. For example:

```
class CustomQueue:

    def __init__(self, lightweight = False):
        if not lightweight:
            # Side effects here...
```

Answer (score 1):

It is OK, but you will need to add a `__del__` method that stops the thread so that the thread doesn't hang around after the CustomQueue object dissapears. This `__del__` method will be called when the CustomQueue instance is garbage collected.